# Calling useQuery() 2 times in the same component results in one of them failing

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I need to make two queries in the same component using apollo.

Following that thread (https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/120 ) I am doing as follow :

```
const {data: dataReviews, loading: loadingReviews, error: errorReviews} = useQuery(GetReviews, {
});
const {data: dataRating, loading: loadingRating, error: errorRating} = useQuery(GetAverage, {
});
```

But this doesn't work for me. Most of the time on of the two requests just fails.

This is the whole code :

```
const Reviews: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const {data: dataReviews, loading: loadingReviews, error: errorReviews} = useQuery(GetReviews, {
        ssr: false,
        variables: {
            offset: 0,
            limit: 3
        }
    });

    const {data: dataRating, loading: loadingRating, error: errorRating} = useQuery(GetAverage, {
        ssr: false
    });
    
    if (loadingRating && loadingReviews) {
        return <div className={`${styles.loader}`}/>;
    }

    const reviews = !loadingReviews && !errorReviews && dataReviews ? dataReviews.reviews[0].reviews : null;
    const rating = !loadingRating && !errorRating && dataRating ? dataRating.average[0] : null;
    
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.netreviews_review_rate_and_stars}`}>
            <div className={`${styles.reviews_list}`}>
                <ReviewsSideInfo rating={rating} stats={reviews.stats} filter={reviews} recommandation={reviews}/>
                <ReviewsContainer reviews={reviews}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Reviews;
```

At the end I get my variable `reviews`  equals `null` and then the rendering fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. That should be working since that solution has been brought up in that specific thread and many people marked it as a valid one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a check to handle the case where both reviews and ratings are NULL.

```
 if (!dataReviews && !dataRating) {
    return null;
}
```

OR

```
 if (!dataReviews || !dataRating) {
    return null;
}
```

Place it beneath `loading` check and you should be good to go.

Comment: I need to wait for the two calls to return before accessing my data and that's not what is happening, though it should be. In my test case especially, the data cannot be null

Comment: In my opinion, that's what causing one of them to fail, because what's happening in your case is that when one of the query comes back with the data, it does not wait for the other to complete and it went to return function. 

If these two cannot be `null` we can put `||` `OR` instead of `AND` condition, then it will have to wait for the other to complete also.

Comment: What would it instantly return since the other condition hasn't been checked ?? How would that make sense ? It is odd. Sometimes it does work, sometime it doesn't.

Comment: What I ended up doing right now is put 
"if (!loadingReviews && !errorReviews && dataReviews && !loadingRating && !errorRating && dataRating) "
Seems to be working. Actually the key point here is to wait for the loading to return, not only wait on the result. Thanks for your input though

Comment: Sounds good, but the simpler approach would have been to have the loadings, errors, and data check separately. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: But in the end I need to check both so it's kind of the same don't you agree ? I mean I need to check them both with an && condition before actually return some content.